# How do i play animation walk for the character?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Nav Mesh Agent to move the character using the mouse click button.
I clicked on bake and it's moving the player.

Now i want to add animation walk to the character while it's moving.
So i added to my character ThirdPersonController Component Animation and in the Animation Inspector i set the Animation property to HumandoidWalk.

But when running the game and clicking with the mouse there is no animation walk.

This is the exception message:

> The animation state Walk could not be played because it couldn't be found!
>   Please attach an animation clip with the name 'Walk' or call this function only for existing animations.
>   UnityEngine.Animation:Play(String)
>   ClickToMove:Update() (at Assets/MyScripts/ClickToMove.cs:21)

This is a screenshot of the character inspector on the right showing the Nav Mesh Agent and the Animator Components and the scripts attached Click To Move:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nobh4.jpg)

And this is the script. First time i tried to make _anim.Play("Walk"); but i got execption since he could not find Walk.

So i tried only _anim.Play(); since i added the HumanoidWalk as animation but now i'm not getting any exceptions but there is no walk animation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animation _anim;

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        _anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _anim.Play("Walk");
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100))
            {
                agent.destination = hit.point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to the console tab then copy and paste the exception to your question.

Comment: I think this better suits [gamedev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or [answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/).

Answer (score 0):

create an animation clip variable and drag the animation to it in the inspector . then try playing the animation by setting the animation to the clip _anim.clip = clipVariable and then use _anim.Play() only . Also you should be using Animator component which is better and not animation component.